# Angular: Is it possible to use *ngIf in relation to list-group-item?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm using a form-group with two items in it. When clicking on one of them should display contents of a component, the same way like clicking on a button, but I would like to use form-group instead of buttons.

For instance with buttons I could use label="xx", so later on I can use this label on a *ngIf to set a boolean condiation. Like this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <button class="btn-outline-primary" Button
    <label = "labelOne">
    (click) = "labelOne=true; labelTwo=false;">
     View Workouts
  </button>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
  <button class="btn-outline-primary" Button
    <label = "labelTwo">
    (click) = "labelOne=false; labelTwo=true;">
     View Exercises
  </button>
</li>

<app-workout *ngIf="labelOne"></app-workout>
```

I would like to use *ngIf to set a boolean condition to display a component if a certain condition is true.

This is my app.component.html code, where at the bottom I would like to render the workout component, if the condition is true.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" label="labelOne">View Workouts</li>
        <li class="list-group-item" label="labelTwo">View Exercise</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    

<app-workout *ngIf="labelOne" ></app-workout>
```

My question is, if it is possible, then how can I implement *ngIf with refering to a form-group-item? The same scenario as I have shown with button example.

**Edit** Added code two examples with code that display nicely and the code that doen't. As you can see adding a button to the same code won't work and won't recognize (click).

This is with form-group that I wish to add a button, but It doesn't work for some reason as you can see on the attached image.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">View Workouts</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">View Exercise></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<!-- This is with button that doesn't work. -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <button class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" Button
                  label = "lbWorkout"
                  <!-- (click) = "lbWorkout=true; lbExercise=false;"> -->
                  Workouts
                </button>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <button class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" Button
                label = "lbExercise"
                  (click) = "lbWorkout=false; lbExercise=true;">
                  Exercises
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any form group in the code you posted. What exactly do you want to achieve? You can put a (click) handler on anything you want. But a button is the correct element to triger such an action.

Comment: @JBNizet the list-group-item is within the <ul class="list-group">. As I mentioned, I would like to use form group to be clickable, where it will show contents of a component.

Comment: `<ul class="list-group">`is an ul, with a CSS class named list-group. What does that have to do with a form group?

Comment: @JBNizet I eddited the question with new code and image. As to your question, I prefere using form-group as it seems better than the button.

Comment: You can add (click) to an `<ul>` or to a `<li>`: tip, change the css `{cursor: pointer;}` to change the cursor

Comment: @Eliseo thanks. I've tried to experience with <ul> <li> and then added button, then I got errors, which I thought it may not be possible to do. The code runs despite showing error at rendering section.